# Python's hash function gives large difference between similar data

Tags: python, hash

Consider the following hashes:

```
>>> hash('ant')
>>> 6440141934328138723
>>> hash('ants')
>>> 1001406009354992019
```

I know the reason why such large difference between two so similar objects is occurring due to implementation of `hash` function.
Are there any other hashing algo which gives close results for objects which are almost similar(like 'ant' and 'ants')?

Basically I wanted to hash strings for using them as features in svm.

Comment: use base64 instead

Comment: If by similar you refer to the pronounciation try algorithms like soundex. There are several python packages out ther.

Answer (score 0):

Python's `hash()` isn't designer for that, however based on your other question about the text features for the SVM, I think you're looking for [stemming and/or lemmatization](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/stemming-and-lemmatization-1.html)

This is going to process your words as to map all related words into a single canonical/normalized word.

Here's an example with [NLTK Python library](http://www.nltk.org/howto/stem.html)

```
>>> stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')
>>> from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
>>> stemmer = SnowballStemmer('english')
>>> stemmer.stem('ant')
u'ant'
>>> stemmer.stem('ants')
u'ant'
>>> stemmer.stem('great')
u'great'
>>> stemmer.stem('greatness')
u'great'
```

Sometimes the stemmer will stem into a string that not really an english word, but that's okay for your purpose, because all you want is for related words to map into the same representation.

```
>>> stemmer.stem('awesome')
u'awesom'
>>> stemmer.stem('awesomeness')
u'awesom'
```